# how can i create in vb.net a reminder of a task every two weeks

Tags: database, vb.net, datagridview

I want to create a task reminder (which the user add it to the database with a start date spot) every two weeks from the date already entered in the database. Based on the position of the day in the week, I made a try but to no avail, if someone has an idea I would be grateful

```
cmd5.CommandText = "select * from task where frequence='2W' "
    da5.SelectCommand = cmd1
    da5.Fill(ds5, "0")
    DataGridView6.Columns.Add("fr", "fr")
    DataGridView6.Columns.Add("class", "class")

    For i As Integer = 0 To ds5.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If Date.Now.DayOfWeek > 3 Then
            If CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek = Date.Now.DayOfWeek Or CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek - ???? = Date.Now.DayOfWeek Then
                DataGridView6.Rows.Add(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4), CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek)
            End If
        End If
        If Date.Now.DayOfWeek < 4 And Date.Now.DayOfWeek <> 0 Then
            If CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek = Date.Now.DayOfWeek Or CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek + ???? = Date.Now.DayOfWeek Then
                DataGridView6.Rows.Add(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(4), CType(ds5.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3), Date).DayOfWeek)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

in "??????" I don't know what i can put to obtain the correct results !! can someone help me please !

Comment: Your code (and what you want to accomplish exactly) is pretty confusing. You want to set a reminder triggered two weeks after the start date in the DB; this is clear but what is the DataGridView doing in all this?, what information you want to input there?

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply.
Regarding the datagridview I want all the spots that will be the subject of recalls, they appear in the datagridview

Comment: No problem. What you mean with "spots that will be the subject of recalls"? Just write down a few bullet points with clear ideas. Example: 1. get the starting date for each user from the DB; 2. check whether the 2 weeks have already passed for each user; 3. If the two weeks have passed, do this; otherwise, do that. Out of these points, I have problems with points number... -> this is clear. Please, try to explain what you want and where you have problems like this: easy for me to understand and for anyone reading this later to relate question/answer to their own problems (-> what SO is about).

Comment: ok, in my database I have a table task (start_date, operation, frequency) ,start_date is the date or the task must be started, operation: what needs to be carried out ,frequency: the task repeats according to the frequency stated eg W weekly 2W every two weeks, M each month .... I have a problem at 2W each reminder two weeks: example, if the task has a start time 01-09-2013, appears in the days of the start date, and when I was in 15-09-2013 obteint a reminder of this task and so on each 2 weeks , SO ?!!

Comment: Things are a bit (but just a tiny bit) clearer: I understand that you want a code to take care of reminders as function of the DB conditions (start date + period (for example: 2W)) and today date. For example: if start date is 1-9-2013 (d-m-yyyy) and the period 2W you want your code to be able to determine that if today is 13-9-2013, nothing should be done; but if today is 15-9-2013 or later a reminder should be trigger. Am I right? Can I ignore all your confusing DataGridView writings and just focus on an algorithm capable to determine if a reminder should be triggered as explained here?

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer. Did I understand you rightly? This is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your comments, you are interested just in the interval-analysis part, that is, in determining whether today's date is before/after the given conditions as defined in your database (with `start_date` and `frequency`). Here you have a sample code to take care of this:

```
Dim start_date As Date = Now.AddDays(-14) 'start_date value to be taken from the DB
Dim frequency As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14) 'Number of days as a function of the given frequency in your DB; this is for 2W.
Dim elapsedDays As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(start_date)

If (elapsedDays >= frequency) Then
    'NOTIFY USER -> it has passed, at least, "frequency" number of days from "start_date"
    If (elapsedDays > frequency) Then
        Dim addDays As Integer = elapsedDays.Subtract(frequency).Days
        Dim dateWhenTargetMet As Date = Now.AddDays(-addDays)
        'Tell user that the target was met "addDays" ago, on "dateWhenTargetMet" 
    End If
End If
```

The code above checks whether the current date equals (or is later than) the `start_date` + `frequency` number of days.